# EF power tools for generating diagrams?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

[EF power tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EntityFramework6PowerToolsCommunityEdition) use to be best tool to generate interactive models from the code first DB context.

1. I tried on .Net 4.7.1 console project. with EF 6.2
2. Fails with following error, what could potentially be tried?

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggregatableProject'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '{FFB2E715-7312-4B93-83D7-D37BCC561C90}'
>   failed due to the following error: No such interface supported
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).    at
>   Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project
>   project)    at
>   Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebProject(Project
>   project)    at
>   Microsoft.DbContextPackage.DbContextPackage.GetUserConfig(Project
>   project, String assemblyFullName)    at
>   Microsoft.DbContextPackage.DbContextPackage.DiscoverUserContextType(Type&
>   systemContextType)

Comment: just trying to understand something - if you are doing code first, why would you want to generate the code from the database?  confusing to me...

Comment: @JohnB for documenting the DB.